# Debian 9 Stretch default login background location

Tags: debian, login, wallpaper

I want to personalize my login a bit, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to change this image.

[image: Default Debian login background image]

I tried changing the .svg's filepaths at /usr/share/wallpapers/DebianThisOrThat by editing the paths directly on the XML configuration file but that wasn't it.

Any ideas? I've searched online but all I've found is for different flavours of desktops and GUIs. This is for the default one that comes up when you do a vanilla Debian install and select "Debian Desktop Environment".

Answer (score 1):

This is called the **Display Manager**.

It looks like you are using LightDM - although I could be wrong. If it is LightDM look at https://wiki.debian.org/LightDM and scroll down to "Change the greeter's background"

GDM is covered by https://wiki.debian.org/GDM Scroll down to "Customizing the GDM appearance."

Comment: you should add the information from the wiki here. It's generally not a very good habit to provide link instead of real answer.

Comment: It doens't seem to be the LightDM configuration. I changed the path under [Greeter] to point to my image (a PNG file) both on `background` and `user-background` and it didn't seem to work. I then went on to  `/usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-background` and changed the paths of `DesktopBackground.xml` to point to my image and tried to `sudo update-alternatives --config desktop-background` but my image didn't show up on the list.

Comment: Oh and I don't even seem to have a GDM3 (to edit `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults`) so I suppose it's not using GDM3 (which I don't know what that is really hehe)